# Pronunciation of "ae" for beginners

Tags: pronunciation

I read in some places on the 'net that the dipthong/digraph æ is pronounced like the "a" in "cat." But all the words I know that contain that word pronounce with the tongue more forward, closer to  a short "e." "Aesthetic," Encyclopaedia," "archaeology." I would go so far as to say it is not so far from the long "a" as in "day."

Can someone clear this up, using language for a non-linguist (someone who would generally not know a digraph from a dipthong, which I had to look up)? I am hoping it is a little more cool and "European" than just "cat."

Comment: This confusion is probably due to the fact that æ in English is used for both the ligature of the letters a and e and also for the single letter ash (æsc or ᚫ) from Old English. The Old English ash should generally be pronounced like the "a" in "cat" (for example, the name-element Alf was originally Ælf), but when it's a ligature representing ae in Latin-derived words (encyclopaedia) or αι in Greek-derived words (aesthetic and archaeology) it will have a different sound.

Comment: The simplest way to find correct pronunciations (and they vary, even for a single given word) is to look up individual words in dictionaries which give audible renderings. eg [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/aesthetic_1)

Comment: The digraph ⟨ae⟩ (more old-fashionedly also ⟨æ⟩) in Modern English almost **never** represents /a/ (as in _cat_). It normally represents /iː/ (as in _she_), /ε/ (as in _them_), or sometimes /eɪ/ (as in _they_) in Latinate plurals like _vertebrae_. There are a very, very small group of words where it is pronounced /a/… but honestly, it’s such a small group of obscure words that I can’t even think of a single one of them now.